# Stop node containing subnodes and text in schema

Tags: .net, xml, xsd

If I have some xml like this:

```
<mynode>
    <mysubnode>
        <mysubsubnode>hello world</mysubsubnode>
        some more text
    </mysubnode>
</mynode>
```

As you can see, `mysubnode` contains both a subnode and some text data.

What I want to know is, is it possible to prevent this happening in a schema? I don't want nodes to contain subnodes *and* text, just subnodes *or* text.

Is there an option in my xsd I can specify to force this?

My program to that uses this xml is written in .NET, so I'll tag it as well incase there's anything of use in .net that I can utilise for this, though I'd much rather that the issue was fixed in the schema itself.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: In re-reading the question, the OP expects to use XSD, not DTD (which btw is a good thing!).  I intially though that DTD was requested; here is the XML Schema (XSD) version

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:complexType name="mysubnodetype" mixed="false">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="mysubsubnode" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="mynodeType" mixed="false">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="mysubnode" type="mysubnodetype"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="mynodeType" type="mynodeType"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Notes: the `mixed="false"` attribute added to the complexTypes is redundant, since by default complexType mixed mode is false (hence, by default, preventing the mixing of elements and text between elements.)

---

*(original answer, with DTD instead)*
The following DTD would prevent this.  Note the fact that mysubnode can only contain a subsubnode, there is no reference of PCDATA w/r mysubnode and therefore the "some more text" of the XML snippet in the question would be invalid.

```
<!ELEMENT mynode (mysubnode)>
<!ELEMENT mysubnode  (mysubsubnode)>
<!ELEMENT mysubsubnode (#PCDATA)>
```

To make the XML snippet of the question valid, something like this would be needed

```
<!ELEMENT mynode (mysubnode)>
<!ELEMENT mysubnode   (#PCDATAT | mysubsubnode)>
<!ELEMENT mysubsubnode (#PCDATA)>
```

Comment: @mjv What about if I wanted to apply this setting globally, to all nodes in my xml file?

Comment: @AndyC: When you define the schema explicitly (i.e. a closed schema), there's no additional effort in specifying that simpleTypes can't contain elements (impossible!) and complexTypes contain text (mixed=false by default).  However, if you define an open schema, it may be possible to restrict say the root element to be an open sequence of complexTypes and/or simpleTypes where the complexTypes are restricted to not allowing mixed.  I'll check into this...